# "Cannot Invoke this function because the current host does not implement it"

Tags: c#, powershell

Using the program here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18409/Asynchronously-Execute-PowerShell-Scripts-from-C

I run into the error: Error in Script: System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Cannot invoke this function because the current host does not implement it. ---> System.Management.Automation.Host.HostException: Cannot Invoke this function because the current host does not implement it.

When using a script I have in a local bin of one of our server, example by just typing in:

*get-serverlist "property group" ServerRange* | CollectPerfData.ps1*

Comment: I think it has to do with adding the PSHost, PSHostUserInterface class, and PSHostRawUserInterface classes...but I can't seem to figure out how to add them into the program source code.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

If you execute script that requires interaction with the host process e.g. Write-Host, Read-Host then you have to implement the host interfaces.  Take a [look at this script](https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=5A8D2641E0963A97&id=5A8D2641E0963A97%217521) for an example of how to do that.

Comment: Could you point out which part of the script is relevant please ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error message recently when I tried to run a PowerShell command via a SQL Server Agent job step. When I ran the command on the host in PowerShell the script prompted me for confirmation. Once I updated the script to not prompt for confirmation anymore the error went away.